# socket.io CORS requests blocked on Safari in Heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, safari, socket.io, cors

I have a React client + Express server and while the app works fine in Chrome and locally in both browsers, when deployed to Heroku I get this in Safari:

```
[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLjfAYA.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLjfTDz. Not allowed to request resource
```

I tried using this on the server `io.origins(['https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com'])` but it didn't help.

The client connects to localhost `const socket = io('http://localhost:5000')` I tried changing it to the Heroku URL and it didn't help. I use proxy in package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```